# How can I add a click event on an individual Element in a mapped array in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, event-handling, react-hooks

I have been trying to increment the quantity of an item in a list, when a caret button corresponding to the item is clicked. But as a react newbie, i have gone through so many methods i have learnt such as using hooks, array methods and still my desired output is not returned.

NB: My desired output, is for a user to be able to click on a caret(either up or down) which will trigger an increment or decrement of the item quantity respectively.

During this struggle, i got a hint to ask for assistance over here(so its my first time). I hope to get my answers...thanks.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { category } from '../categories.json';
import {
    Card,
    CardBody,
    CardTitle
  } from 'reactstrap';
  import { faCaretDown, faCaretUp } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
  import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

const Sides = () => {

    let [count, setCount] = useState(1)

    function Increment(event) {
        console.log(event.target);
        
        let sides = category[0].sides.forEach(item => {
            let targetId = event.target.dataset.id;
            item.find((item)=> item.id !== targetId)
        })
        console.log(sides.id);

        if(sides) {
            setCount(count + 1);
        }
        
    }

    const Decrement = () => {
        console.log('Decreasing');
        
    }

    function renderNames() {
        return(
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>items</th>
                        <th>qty</th>
                        <th>price</th>
                        <th>check</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                {category[0].sides.map(item => (
                    <tr key={item.id}>
                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td style={{display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <div style={{display: 'grid'}}>
                    <div onClick={Increment}  >
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCaretUp} data-id={item.id}/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCaretDown}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    {count}
                </td>
                <td>{item.price}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="" id=""/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <>
        <Card>
            <CardTitle>
            <h2>Sides list</h2>
            </CardTitle>

            <CardBody>
            <div style={{display: 'flex', padding: '5px'}}>
            {renderNames()}
            </div>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
        </>
    )
}

export default Sides;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to start thinking the React way, so no `data-x` attributes needed, to achieve same effect you can pass item id with the click event like

```
<div onClick={() => Increment(item.id)}>
```

But let's do it even more the `React` way, break your components makes it even better

First create an Item component

```
export const Item = ({ item }) => {
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
    const { id, name, price } = item;

    const Increment = () => {
        setCount(count + 1);
    };

    return (
        <tr>
            <td>{name}</td>
            <td style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <div style={{ display: 'grid' }}>
                    <div onClick={Increment}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCaretUp} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCaretDown} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                {count}
            </td>
            <td>{price}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
};
```

Then map through items and render `Item` component

```js
const Sides = () => {
    function renderNames() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>items</th>
                            <th>qty</th>
                            <th>price</th>
                            <th>check</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {category[0].sides.map(item => (
                            <Item key={item.id} item={item} />
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <Card>
            <CardTitle>
                <h2>Sides list</h2>
            </CardTitle>

            <CardBody>
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', padding: '5px' }}>
                    {renderNames()}
                </div>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
    );
};
```

The problem you are facing is that you also use one `state` to update items count which will not work as expected, this way of breaking things, each item has it's own state and when updated it will be reflected for that item only

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using a single `count`, you can use an array of `counts` and map it with the `sides` array by the `index`,

The count of `sides[0]` is `counts[0]`, count of `sides[1]` is `counts[1]` ...

Try this:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { category } from '../categories.json';
import {
    Card,
    CardBody,
    CardTitle
  } from 'reactstrap';
  import { faCaretDown, faCaretUp } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
  import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

const Sides = () => {

    let [counts, setCounts] = useState([])

    const Increment = (index) => {
      let newCounts = [...counts]
      newCounts[index] += 1
      setCounts(newCounts);        
    }

    const Decrement = (index) => {
      if (counts[index] > 0) {
        let newCounts = [...counts]
        newCounts[index] -= 1
        setCounts(newCounts);
      }
    }

    function renderNames() {
        return(
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>items</th>
                        <th>qty</th>
                        <th>price</th>
                        <th>check</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                {category[0].sides.map((item, index) => (
                    <tr key={item.id}>
                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td style={{display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <div style={{display: 'grid'}}>
                    <div onClick={() => Increment(index)}  >
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCaretUp} data-id={item.id}/>
                    </div>
                    <div  onClick={() => Decrement(index)}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCaretDown}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    {counts[index]}
                </td>
                <td>{item.price}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="" id=""/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <>
        <Card>
            <CardTitle>
            <h2>Sides list</h2>
            </CardTitle>

            <CardBody>
            <div style={{display: 'flex', padding: '5px'}}>
            {renderNames()}
            </div>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
        </>
    )
}

export default Sides;
```

Comment: Tried this too but it keeps giving me errors, `too many re-renders`